# R.java not to generate

Tags: java, android, xml, resources

My menu files are causing my R.java not to generate. I am not sure what the error could be.
Here are the .xml files:

display_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: is there any parent or tag that contains those `items`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are correctly saving your `main.xml` and `display_message.xml` in the `res/menu` folder.

You need to add the `menu` tag. Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```